# Help with 'Missing these required gems: error'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I get this error with gems that I install from github.

I am on a XP machine.

This time I installed,

giraffesoft-is_taggable gem.  gem list says it's there.

I created a sample rails app and added config.gem "giraffesoft-is_taggable" to the environment.rb file.

Start the app and I get the error:

Missing these required gems:
  giraffesoft-is_taggable

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
config.gem 'giraffesoft-is_taggable', :lib => 'is_taggable', :source => 'http://gems.github.com'
```

I believe github prefixes gems with the user's name to avoid clashing with rubyforge so you have to specify the actual lib.

I've also seen a similar problem on linux where I installed a gem as a regular account (i.e. not root) and it installed the gem to my home directory which rails doesn't know about.  gem list would still report it as installed.

Comment: Son of a gun! It sure does work!

Dang!, Glad I asked.

Thank you very much.